# Wireguard не меняет ip при double vpn

Tags: vpn, wireguard

При подключении к серверу использую VPN, при запуске и подключении к Wireguard на клиенте подключение отображается, но ip адрес остается 1 VPN.

Конфиг на сервере:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 55809
PrivateKey = server_private_key

[Peer]
PublicKey = client_public_key
AllowedIPs =10.0.0.2/32
```

Конфиг на клиенте:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
PrivateKey = klient_private_key

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_public_key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24
PersistentKeepalive = 10
Endpoint = server_ip:55809
```

Подключение происходит и они обмениваются пакетами, но ip не меняется, возможно вопрос в маршрутах или отдельных настройках на клиенте, подскажите пожалуйста те кто знают, или сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, как оказалось со стороны хостинга, скорей всего блокируются пакеты wireguard